# List of languages with active or native speakers

Tags: data-request, language, global

I'm looking for a simple list that has a count of speakers per language. It can be either active speaker or native speakers, the exactness doesn't matter so much to me.

Any format, any license. It's not for research and just for fun - so the exactness is not so important.

Dream data:

```
Mandarin,9350000000
Spanish,390000000
English,365000000
Hindi,295000000
....
Chamicuro,20
Ongota,12
Njerep,6
Lemerig,2
```

---

There are many datasets, but I can only find "top" languages

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_total_number_of_speakers#Ethnologue_(2017_20th_edition)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers#Top_languages_by_population

or "least" languages

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_last_known_speakers_of_languages

Comment: Well, [Ethnologue Global Dataset](https://www.ethnologue.com/sites/default/files/Ethnologue-20-Global%20Dataset%20Doc.pdf) is (not freely) available under Personal Research License.

Comment: seems they would have the data, but no free access.

Answer (score 1):

This [table of ISO language tags](http://cstrobbe.github.io/languagelearning/misc/languagetags.html) has the number of native speakers in the penultimate column. Some of the numbers are rough estimates, some are based on a census for that specific language or the country where a specific language is spoken. The table also lists a number of extinct languages but does not list languages that have no ISO tag. Note also that some of the languages in the table are actually [macro languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639_macrolanguage). (The JSON file that is available on that site only has language tags and language names, not the number of native speakers.)

Comment: It's a good resource, but way less than the estimated 6900 global languages